# An invalid request URI was provided in datatable webapi calling

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, datatable

```
An invalid request URI was provided. The request URI must either be an absolute URI or BaseAddress must be set.
```

Here is the Api Controller:

```
EmailTemplate.UI\Areas\Ticket\Api\TicketController.cs
```

HERE IS THE CODE:

```
  var client = new HttpClient();


                string _url = _apiTicket + "Areas/Ticket/Api/TicketController/Get/10?PageIndex=" + pageIndex + "&PageSize=" + pageSize;
                var response = client.GetAsync(_url).Result;
                var result1 = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

here in response this error comes.

i want to filter data by pageIndex and pagesize in datatable server side mvc 4.

Here is the method in api:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get1(int UserId)
    {
        string _searchString = GetQueryValueByName.Get(Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs(), "searchstr");
        int _start = int.Parse(GetQueryValueByName.Get(Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs(),"start"));
        int _length =int.Parse(GetQueryValueByName.Get(Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs(),"length"));
        List<sp_Ticketlist_Result> _dbData;
        int _dataTotaRowCount;
        _dbData = _repository.GetTicket(UserId).ToList();
        _dataTotaRowCount = _dbData.Count();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_searchString))
        {
            _dbData = _dbData.Where(m =>
            m.Name.ToUpper().Contains(_searchString.ToUpper())).ToList();
            _dataTotaRowCount = _dbData.Count();
            _dbData = _dbData.Skip(_start).Take(_length).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            _dbData = _dbData.Skip(_start).Take(_length).ToList();
        }
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK,DataTableObjectConverter.ConvertData(_dbData, _dataTotaRowCount));
    }
    public static class GetQueryValueByName
    {
        public static string Get(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> _req,
                                 string key)
        {
            return _req.FirstOrDefault(ma => string.Compare(ma.Key, key) ==
                                      0).Value;
        }
    }
    public static class DataTableObjectConverter
    {
        public static DataTableObject ConvertData<T>(T source, int count)
            where T : class, new()
        {
            DataTableObject _obj = new DataTableObject();
            //_obj.draw = 1;
            _obj.recordsFiltered = count;
            _obj.recordsTotal = count;
            _obj.data = source;
            return _obj;
        }
    }
```

Is there need for any method with pageIndex and pagesize??

how do i call data through pageIndex  and pagesize defines in method??

Here is my GetData method:

```
   public ActionResult GetData()
        {
            // Initialization.
            JsonResult result = new JsonResult();

            try
            {
                // Initialization.
                string search = Request.Form.GetValues("search[value]")[0];
                string draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw")[0];
                string order = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]")[0];
                string orderDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]")[0];
                int startRec = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form.GetValues("start")[0]);
                //  int pageSize = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form.GetValues("length")[0]);


                var start = Request.Form.GetValues("start").FirstOrDefault();
                var length = Request.Form.GetValues("length").FirstOrDefault();
                int pageSize = length != null ? Convert.ToInt32(length) : 0;
                int recordStatr = start != null ? Convert.ToInt32(start) : 0;
                recordStatr = recordStatr == 0 ? 1 : recordStatr;
                var pageIndex = (recordStatr / pageSize) + 1;
                int recordsTotal = 0;
                // Loading.
                List<AppTicket> data = this.LoadData();

                // Total record count.
                int totalRecords = data.Count;

                // Verification.
                //if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(search) &&
                //    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(search))
                //{
                //    // Apply search
                //    data = data.Where(p => p.Title.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) ||
                //                           p.Name.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) ||
                //                           p.Email.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())).ToList();
                //    //p.ProductName.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) ||
                //    //p.SpecialOffer.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) ||
                //    //p.UnitPrice.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()) ||
                //    //p.UnitPriceDiscount.ToString().ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower())).ToList();
                //}

                // Sorting.
                data = this.SortByColumnWithOrder(order, orderDir, data);

                // Filter record count.
                int recFilter = data.Count;

                // Apply pagination.
                // data = data.Skip(startRec).Take(pageSize).ToList();

                // Loading drop down lists.
                // result = this.Json(new { draw = Convert.ToInt32(draw), recordsTotal = totalRecords, recordsFiltered = recFilter, data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);





                //Find Order Column
                //var sortColumn = Request.Form.GetValues("columns[" + Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]").FirstOrDefault() + "][name]").FirstOrDefault();
                //var sortColumnDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]").FirstOrDefault();




                var client = new HttpClient();


                //client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:1849");
                //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                // client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
                // string _url = _apiTicket + ".Get?UserId=" + 10 + "&PageIndex=" + pageIndex + "&PageSize=" + pageSize;
                //var response = client.GetAsync(_url).Result;
                //var response1 = client.GetAsync("/Areas/Ticket/Api/Get/10,10,10").Result;
                //if (response1.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                //{
                //    string responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                //}
               // string _url = _apiTicket + "Get1/10?searchstr=Monaj&PageIndex=" + pageIndex + "&PageSize=" + pageSize;
                //  string apiUrl = "Api/Ticket/10?searchstr=Monaj&PageIndex=" + pageIndex + "&PageSize=" + pageSize;
                string apiUrl = "../Areas/api/Ticket/1?searchstr=Monaj&start=0&length=10";
                var response = client.GetAsync(apiUrl).Result;
                var result1 = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;



                // HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(_url);
                //  HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(_url).Result;
                //var response = client.GetAsync(_url).Result;
                // var result1 = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                JsonResult jsonresult = Json(result1, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                AppTicket _contacts = new AppTicket();

                _contacts = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AppTicket>(jsonresult.Data.ToString());

                //return Json(new { draw = draw, recordsFiltered = recordsTotal, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = _contacts.listcourses }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                result = this.Json(new { draw = Convert.ToInt32(draw), recordsFiltered = totalRecords, recordsTotal = recordsTotal, data = data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);




            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Info
                Console.Write(ex);
            }

            // Return info.
            return result;
        }
```

I am using the json ajax here in custom-datatable.js.
here is the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function ()
{
  debugger
    $('#TableId').DataTable(
    {
        //"columnDefs": [
        //    { "width": "5%", "targets": [0] },
        //    {
        //        "className": "text-center custom-middle-align",

        //        "targets": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
        //    },
        //],
        'columnDefs': [{
            'targets': 0,
            'searchable': false,
            'orderable': false,
            'width': '1%',
            'className': 'dt-body-center',


            'render': function (data, type, full, meta) {
                return '<input type="checkbox">';
            }
        }
        ,
          {
              targets: 2,
              render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                  if (type === 'display') {
                      data = '<a href="/TicketTemplate/AppDetails/' + row.Id + ' " >' + data + '</a>';
                  }

                  return data;
              }
          },

          {
              targets: 1,
              render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                   return moment(data).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss');                 
              }
          }
        ],
        "language":
            {
                "processing": "<div class='overlay custom-loader-background'><i class='fa fa-cog fa-spin custom-loader-color'></i></div>"
            },
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax":
            {
                "url": "/TicketTemplate/GetData",
                "type": "POST",
                "dataType": "JSON"
            },
        "columns": [
                   { "data": '' },
                    { "data": "CreatedDate" },
                    { "data": "Title" },
                     //{
                     //    //"data": "title",
                     //    "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                     //        //return '<a href=\"' + title + '\">' + title + '</a>';
                     //        return '<a href="' + title + '">' + data + '</a>';
                     //    }
                     //},
                      //{
                      //{
                      //    //"data": "title",
                      //    "render": function (data, type, row, meta) {
                      //        //return '<a href=\"' + title + '\">' + title + '</a>';
                      //        return "<a href=" + "/" + "/TicketTemplate/AppDetails/" + row.Id + "   id=" + row.Id + ">" + row.Title + " </a>";


                      //    }
                      //},

                    { "data": "Name" },
                    { "data": "Email" },
                    { "data": "AssignTo" },
                    { "data": "Status" }                  
        ]




    });
});
```

First of all it hit the Mvc controller GetData() and in GetData() call the Api Controller Get().
Paging sorting searching all are in using api dynamically.

Comment: Could not understand ur code. Can u please make it properly, which are Api Controller method ??

Comment: In your Api method, there is no pageIndex and pagesize defined. It is returning all the values by userId in a list. Then why are you passing pageIndex and pagesize ??

Comment: in the above case in Get controller i want to call

Comment: i am using   string _url = _apiTicket + "/Get/10/PageIndex=" + pageIndex + "/PageSize=" + pageSize;

Comment: but not working

Comment: fetch the value by page index and pagesize

Comment: This is seems like correct only. Where r u getting error ? Or what u want ??

Comment: i want to call the datatable paging sorting seraching through mvc controller and web api controller

Comment: the error is on   var response = client.GetAsync(_url).Result;

Comment: there is a problem to call the webapi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned in your comment that, "**i want to call the datatable paging sorting searching through MVC controller and web api controller**", then I would recommend to do like this, that is what i have done in many projects.

```
//This is my API Get method
public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id)
 {
  string _searchString = 
  GetQueryValueByName.Get(Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs(), "searchstr");
  int _start = 
  int.Parse(GetQueryValueByName.Get(Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs(), 
            "start"));
  int _length = 
  int.Parse(GetQueryValueByName.Get(Request.GetQueryNameValuePairs(), 
           "length"));
  List<sp_Ticketlist_Result> _dbData;
  int _dataTotaRowCount;
  _dbData = _repository.GetTicket(id).ToList();
  _dataTotaRowCount = _dbData.Count();
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_searchString))
      {
       _dbData = _dbData.Where(m => 
       m.Name.ToUpper().Contains(_searchString.ToUpper())).ToList();
       _dataTotaRowCount = _dbData.Count();
       _dbData = _dbData.Skip(_start).Take(_length).ToList();
       }
   else
      {
       _dbData = _dbData.Skip(_start).Take(_length).ToList();
      }
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, 
    DataTableObjectConverter.ConvertData(_dbData, _dataTotaRowCount));
  }
```

Bellow is my GetQueryValueByName and DataTableObjectConverter Class, that i kept in a separated class file and just reference to my Api Controller.

```
public static class GetQueryValueByName
{
 public static string Get(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> _req, 
                          string key)
    {
     return _req.FirstOrDefault(ma => string.Compare(ma.Key, key) == 
                               0).Value;
    }
}

public static class DataTableObjectConverter
{
    public static DataTableObject ConvertData<T>(T source, int count) 
        where T : class, new()
    {
        DataTableObject _obj = new DataTableObject();
        //_obj.draw = 1;
        _obj.recordsFiltered = count;
        _obj.recordsTotal = count;
        _obj.data = source;
        return _obj;
    }
}

public class DataTableObject
{
    public int recordsTotal { get; set; }
    public int recordsFiltered { get; set; }
    public Object data { get; set; }
}
```

Then my URL will be like this,

```
string apiUrl = "http://localhost:55442/api/Ticket/1?
                 searchstr=Monaj&start=0&length=10";
var client = new HttpClient();
var response = client.GetAsync(apiUrl).Result;
var result1 = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

**Note:** See, here I'm passing start,length,search string as query string and I'm fetching them in my Api Get method. Just update your URL here and don't give **/** in query string parameters. You have written like this,

```
" + pageIndex + "/PageSize=" + pageSize;
```

This is wrong. Check how I have done. You need to separate by **&**

Comment: GetQueryValueByName what is this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138728/discussion-between-basanta-matia-and-manoj).